# how to REAL TIME track my cursor to a coordinate? (DIY aimbot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, mouse, mediapipe

i need to track my cursor to the nose of a human to create a DIY aimbot with pose detection.

(just for fun, not intending to cheat, there would be so many better and easier options than to make my own)

i already have the first part of the code and it shows you your screen and the skeleton, as well as the exact coordinates of the nose with no problem,

but the method that im using to move my cursor over to that point is not working

im using `mouse.move` and have tried other stuff like pyautogui, tkinter.

it doesn't give me an error but still does not work

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import time
import pyautogui
import mouse

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose


# display screen resolution, get it from your OS settings
SCREEN_SIZEX = (1920)
SCREEN_SIZEY = (1080)
# define the codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
# create the video write object
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (SCREEN_SIZEX, SCREEN_SIZEY))

with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.1, min_tracking_confidence=0.9) as pose:
    while True:
        # make a screenshot
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
        frame = np.array(img)
        # convert colors from BGR to RGB
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # Recolor image to RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False

        # Make detection
        results = pose.process(image)

        # Recolor back to BGR
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        try:
            landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            lndmark = landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value]
            x = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].x]
            y = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].y]
            #print(x)
            #print(y)
            mouse.move(x, y)
        except:
            pass

        # Render detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2),
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )

        # write the frame
        out.write(frame)

        pTime = 0

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(image, str(int(fps)), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
        (255, 0, 0), 3)



        cv2.imshow('Mediapipe Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    #for lndmark in mp_pose.PoseLandmark:
        #print(lndmark)
```

this is the part that doesn't work:

```
       try:
            landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            lndmark = landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value]
            x = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].x]
            y = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].y]
            mouse.move(x, y)
        except:
            pass
```

i would assume that it is beacuse x and y are supposed to numbers or somehow it can't read or proccess it correctly

but it doesn't give me an error, so im asking it here hoping on of you guys had already figured this one out

Comment: Are you sure your code is able to get the X and Y coordinate? I think some error might have occurred while finding the x and y coordinate in this line... ```x = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].x]``` and ```y = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].y]```. Try printing these values and tell me if it is actually returning some values.

Comment: The reason it doesn't give you an error is because it is inside the try except block. And you have set except to pass